# JXBrowser - playing m3u8

Tags: plugins, m3u8, jxbrowser

Is JxBrowser able to play m3u8 content? 
Chrome can through an extension but JxBrowser does'nt use extensions.
I could not find any PPAPI plugin for that..

Any idea?
Thx,
Romain.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Chromium issue tracker and forum, they don't have plans to implement the support of playing the m3u8 content.
Therefore, it doesn't look that there is a possibility to play such a content in JxBrowser.